# Pass selected items as comma separated strings in ActionLink parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I tried below code in Razor and I'm trying to pass selected item values (from `Model.NewList`) as a parameter (comma separated strings) in the link (`New Link`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.ActionLink("New Link", 
                        "NewAction", 
                        "NewController", 
                        new { columns = 3,
                              locations = String.Join(",", Model.NewList
                                            .Where(m => m.Checked == true)
                                            .Select(m => m.Code))

                        }, 
                        new { @class = "btn btn-success" })

    for (var i = 0; i < Model.NewList.Count(); i++)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.NewList[i].Checked)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewList[i].Code)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewList[i].Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

Problem with this is it is not picking up the items selectd by user (`.Where(m => m.Checked == true`) as it runs on page load, when no items are selected. How to update the model as user select the items and pick selected items when clicks on the action link?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` is razor code. Its parsed on the server before its sent to the view. If you want to send the edited values, you need to dynamically build the url using javascript. But why are you not posting a form? And in any case, `NewList` is a complex object so this could never work unless your query string is `?[0].Code=someValue&[0].Name=someValue&[1].Code=someValue&....`

Comment: Looks like you misunderstand what is client-side and server-side.

Comment: You may need to parse `Model.NewList` in controller action and prepare `location` comma separated string there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I should post data and redirect from controller then..

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the data from your form not from the model that you initially passed to your view (Model.xxxx).
I would use the data submitted by the form by changing the ActionLink to a submit button and pointing the form action to the action and controller desired.
The form collection you will receive will contain the checked values.